# Mongoose, moving one array element into another array of different parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a schema like this: Every institution has X number of professionals.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var profSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    userRefID : { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    Status : Boolean,
    initLic : Date,  
    endLic :  Date

});

var instSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name : String,
    professional : [profSchema]

});

mongoose.model('Inst', instSchema);
var Inst = mongoose.model('Inst');


mongoose.model('Prof', profSchema);
var Prof = mongoose.model('Prof');
```

The data is shown below, lets say I want to move the professional with ObjectId("56e05bbfb37d4c7c4c2c45b7") of intitutionA to institutionB and update its InitLic and EndLic field, how can I accomplish that with mongoose? I've been trying to solve this by finding the element in the first parent and then pushing it into the other while removing the duplicate in the first parent but it doesn't seem right to me.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e05b70b37d4c7c4c2c45b3"),
    "name" : "InstituitionA",
    "professional" : [ 
        {
            "endLic" : ISODate("2016-04-08T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "initLic" : ISODate("2016-03-09T17:20:49.523Z"),
            "Status" : true,
            "userRefID" : ObjectId("56e05b7cb37d4c7c4c2c45b4"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("56e05b7cb37d4c7c4c2c45b5")
        }, 
        {
            "endLic" : ISODate("2016-04-08T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "initLic" : ISODate("2016-03-09T17:21:57.441Z"),
            "Status" : true,
            "userRefID" : ObjectId("56e05bbeb37d4c7c4c2c45b6"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("56e05bbfb37d4c7c4c2c45b7")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e05c5f35ae7b6017e39ad4"),
    "name" : "InstituitionB",
    "professional" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use your model Prof  and reference it in instSchema's professional property instead of embedding profSchema. Now it seems that you are not using your Prof model at all. I would change `professional : [profSchema]` to `professional : [{ type:...ObjectId, ref:'Prof'}]` and add to profSchema `instId` so when you want to move professional then you simply update instId to move professional from institution A to B

Comment: well its a nice solution. But doesn't making everything with references, defeat the propose of using mongoDB?

Comment: In certain cases yes but not always. In your case do you even need the profSchema? Can't all prof props be part of user? Then you would only have one ref

Comment: Yes I need to separate them because there are several types of users, Professionals belong to Institutions and Patients will belong belong to Groups and Professionals.